# Cordova Media Capture CaptureVideoOptions duration not working

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

The media capture plugin is working great except for the part where I set the duration in the CaptureVideoOptions. Tried setting is to various numbers, nothing will stop the video at that time. However, the limit option seems to work as well as all the other capture options for images and audio recording. I am testing on Nexus 5 version 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This does for me. Tested on various devices.

```
let options: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 1, duration: 5, quality:0};
MediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
      // code
}
```

Comment: I believe I am using similar code, but I will try it anyways. Thanks

Comment: I used the exact same code, and I have also tried it on latest Android version (7.1.1) with no success. Anyone facing this problem??

Comment: not working for me either.. latest android nougat its not working on my oneplus 5t.. not even quality is working in it

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm facing the exact same problem also with a Nexus 5 Android 6.0.1. On other test devices the timer counts down and not up like on the Nexus, and they seem to work. (tested on Emulator with Android 4.4 and Lenovo P2 with Android 7.0.0, both without issues.

Answer (score 0):

duration parameter will not help to restrict the video recording using cordova-media-captuire-plugin.
but, it will help you, not to upload the recorded video with more than the specified duration.
So, you can use duration parameter to restrict the video uploading to server. That will complete your goal.
Hope it helps.
Thanks